# How does each of ps2pdf, pdfcrop, pdftops, epstool and epstopdf invoke GhostScript behind the scene?

Tags: ghostscript

I want to know the syntax to invoke GhostScript directly to get the same effect as each of the following command does.

1. `ps2pdf input.ps`
2. `pdfcrop --hires input`
3. `pdftops -eps input.pdf`
4. `epstool --copy --bbox input.eps output.eps`
5. `epstopdf --hires input.eps`

Comment: Use the source Luke! Use the source!

Comment: @Martin: I cannot read perl script.

Comment: @Jasper: [Luke Skywalker](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LTsvOHq3xc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get this by looking at the source code of these tools. Most of them are scripts, which compile a list of Ghostscript options depending on their command line options and execute it at the end. In order to get the `$OPTIONS` variables etc. decoded automatically you can make a copy of these scripts and add an `echo` before the final command so it is printed in the terminal and not executed. An even simpler alternative is to start them using `$SHELL -x script --args` which is the shell debug mode (at least for `sh` and `bash`) which prints all executed commands.

For your 1. I get:

```
gs -P- -dSAFER -q -P- -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=input.pdf -P- -dSAFER -c .setpdfwrite -f input.ps
```

Number 2. is a Perl script and is only using GS for the BBox extraction (as my `fixbb` script does I mentioned in your other question):

```
gs -sDEVICE=bbox -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -c save pop -f input.pdf
```

Number 3. is a program not a script and uses `libpoppler` internally to do the conversion, not Ghostscript.

Number 4. again simply uses Ghostscript for BBox extraction which is then placed into the otherwise unchanged file. Here the BBox is written to a temp file first.

```
"gs"  -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=bbox   -c "> setpagedevice" -f "/tmp/gsviewnIk3kp"
```

Number 5 uses (displayed using the `--debug` option):

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=input.pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dAutoRotatePages=/None - -c quit
```

Comment: by the way: the `-dSAFER` shouldn't be used when the converted PS file has to read and/or write from/to external files. It forbits such operations

Comment: @xport: The GS command line argument should be about the same, maybe different styles (e.g. arguments start with `/` not `-`). In this case it would by batch scripts (`.bat`) but also here `echo` works.

Comment: I think your answer for number 2 does not work as `pdfcrop --hires input.pdf`.

Comment: @Martin: Are you sure that `-P` switch occurs thrice and `-dSAFER` option occurs twice in `ps2pdf`?

Comment: Is there one for `ps2eps input.ps` as well?

Answer (score 6):

Where is the problem? Do a `` cat `which ps2pdf` `` under Linux or `type ....` under Windows (don't know if it has the same "which" feature as Linux) .

`epstool` is a program not a script.

Comment: @Joseph: how do I get the backticks inside backticks?

Comment: Press the edit button, you will see how to escape backtick. Inner backticks must be enclosed by a pair of double backticks.

Comment: @Herbert: if I'm not wrong, starting from the NT family, Windows has now a command called `where`, which is very similar to the good old Linux `which` (it seems to incorporate some `find` features as well). :-)

Answer (score 4):

Most of these are shell/perl scripts so you can easily see what they do. They all do a bit (or a lot) more than simply invoking `gs` though, so I'll just give the main option they use. You'll have to read the code to see exactly what:

1. `-sDEVICE=pdfwrite`
2. `-sDEVICE=bbox`
3. Not based on ghostscript!
4. `-sDEVICE=bbox`
5. `-sDEVICE=pdfwrite`

Comment: +1 but number 5 `-sDEVICE=epswrite` ?

Comment: Nope. `epstopdf` is producing pdf, so it uses `pdfwrite`