# Printing selected chapters without affecting cross-referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters, include

I am writing my thesis in Lyx and for some reason, probably due to the style sheet, I am unable to print the complete thesis. It gives weird errors. However, individually all chapters are easily converted to PDF.

Is there a command that allows printing only a few selected chapters but does not affect referencing? I could then restart page numbering and get a quick fix to the problem.

Please advise.

Answer (score 5):

Use `\includeonly`

```
\documentclass{book}

%\includeonly{Introduction}% uncomment this line if you want to include chapter "Introduction" only without affecting the referencing.

\begin{document}
\include{Introduction}
\include{Summary}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was inspired by a comment in this http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22109/2099. :-)