# How do I compile tex chapters?

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I want to compile and view just the chapter I'm working on. How do I do this? It seems way harder to do than it should be.

**Clarification:** I'm not trying to print the main document with only a subset of chapters. I'm trying to compile a specific chapter as its own document without any of the additional text baggage carried in the main document. The real-world problem to be solved is that I'm working on a chapter of my thesis but cannot easily see what it will look like as a PDF document; I am currently jumping back and forth between uncompilable and compilable (but cluttered) documents to see the chapter I am building.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Printing selected chapters without affecting cross-referencing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22735/5764); [Typeset single chapter from book](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8400/5764)

Comment: Create the chapters on separate .tex files and then use the `\include{<chapter name here>}` command in your main file and compile. Comment out the chapters you do not want.

Comment: Chapters in separated files (`*.tex`), including them by [`\include`](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/*checkout*/latexrefman/trunk/latex2e.html#g_t_005cinclude) and compiling selected chapters by [`\includeonly`](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/*checkout*/latexrefman/trunk/latex2e.html#g_t_005cincludeonly) should do the trick.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear in my description. I'm not trying to print the main document with only a subset of chapters. I'm trying to compile a specific chapter as its own document without any of the additional text baggage carried in the main document.

Comment: @dylanlknowles: What is wrong with using `\include` for all chapters and `\includeonly` for the one you're interested in seeing. Sure this will include the title page, perhaps acknowledgements and maybe a ToC/LoF/LoT, but you can comment those out easily, can't you?

Comment: Good point. It'll be a bit awkward -- our university's thesis format has a lot of text / control mixing -- but there's no reason I can't try. This said, it still leaves me switching between windows. It'd be nice if I could just have a PDF / Latex split on my monitor.

Comment: Create all your content in compartmentalized files, and `\input` them, while `\chapters` could follow a `\include`/`\includeonly` approach. I'm still not following the problems you may be experiencing...

Comment: If you're really interested in what the final output will look like in university thesis style, you'll pretty much have to use their documentclass and/or style file, with whatever front matter commented out as needed. Otherwise, you'll have to match their margins, line spacing, etc. on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt, The [`pagesel`](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/pagesel.pdf) package I use this package to compile to individual chapters. Abstract: Single pages or page areas can be selected for output.

```
\usepackage[2-5]{pagesel}
```

There are some more answers, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96256/compiling-only-a-page-range-or-page-selection).